# Create a form submit button that enables "open in new window" when the user right clicks?

Tags: javascript, forms, form-submit, right-click

I have a form submit button that I need to enable the user to be able to right click and get the "open in new window" option, so that the user can have the option of either submitting the form in the current window (by simply clicking the button) or in a new window (by right clicking and selecting "open in new window"). Is this possible?

I know I could sort of do this via creating a stand-alone link/image and use css to make it look like a button, and then use onclick to submit the form when clicked, but this would not work for users that does not have javascript.

UPDATE: To clarify, I am looking for a way to do this without using javascript, or confirm that it is actually impossible to do so without using javascript.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, this is impossible without using JavaScript.

Comment: For right click check this one http://javascript.internet.com/page-details/right-click-menu.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is have the stand-alone link/image with CSS as you propose, and then use a `<noscript>` tag to replace it with a traditional form button when Javascript isn't available.

Comment: The problem with the noscript approach is that for non-js users, they would not be able to right click and get the "open in new window" option. So basically, I am looking for a way to enabling right click on a form submit button without using javascript.

Comment: There is no standard way to provide an "open in new window" option on form controls, and thus any solution you come up with is only going to work in some use cases. But remember that even having multiple WINDOWS isn't a guaranteed feature of every web browser (lynx, w3m, etc.). There are some things you just can't do everywhere. Such is life.